# Is a subclass only inheriting some properties from a superclass bad practice?

Tags: oop

I have a subclass which inherits the properties and methods of a super class. However, I want this subclass to only inherit some of the properties from the superclass, not all of them.

In OO programming, is this bad practice? I have noticed that it is impossible to do in ES6 JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

### This is not possible in OOP

If you define `B` as subclass of `A`, then `B` inherits all the properties and methods from `A`.

There are some exceptions:

- **private members** of `A` will not be accessible in `B` (BTW the code will be there)
- **initializers/constructors** are not always automatically inherited, here the rules depend on the language you are using